# Maps in Xamarin Forms with .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, maps

I want to put maps in my Xamarin Forms app but I'm having troubles due to the framework version used. When I try to install Xamarin.Forms.Maps the Visual Studio tells me that is not compatible and is reverting the changes.

There is any way to put maps in Xamarin Forms + .Net Standard 2.0 project? Thanks

> Install-Package: Degradation of the detected package: Xamarin.Forms from 2.5.1.444934 to 2.5.0.122203. Refer to the package directly from the project to select a different version.
>    MyProject-> Xamarin.Forms.Maps 2.5.1.444934 -> Xamarin.Forms (> = 2.5.1.444934)
>    MyProject-> Xamarin.Forms (> = 2.5.0.122203)
>   Online: 1 Character: 1
>   + Install-Package Xamarin.Forms.Maps -Version 2.5.1.444934
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId: NuGetCmdletUnhandledException, NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>    
>   Install-Package: Failed to restore the package. Reversing the package changes for 'MyProject'.
>   Online: 1 Character: 1
>   + Install-Package Xamarin.Forms.Maps -Version 2.5.1.444934
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId: NuGetCmdletUnhandledException, NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>    
>   Elapsed time: 00: 00: 01.3940707

Comment: What is the actual nuget error?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the error message I'm getting.This occurs when I install it on my base project, but for example when I try to install it in my Android project (MyProject.Android) this works fine.